# How to wait until context value has been set | React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do I wait until context value has been set?

I had a problem where I couldn't get the value from my context, so when I needed it I always got the initial value, `""`. So now I have a `useEffect` in my component,

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (posContext.activePaymentTabId) {
        console.log("poscontext i useeffect", posContext); <-- can see my value here now
        // handlePaymentResponse(true, "GODKÄNT");
    }
}, [posContext.activePaymentTabId]);
```

I set my value in this function:

```
const makeCardPayment = async () => {
    posContext.handleSetActivePaymentTabId(); // <-- Here I set my value that I need later
    try {
        const res = await functionA();

        return functionB(res.foo);

    } catch (error) {}
};
```

But in `functionB` where my value is needed:

```
const functionB = (foo) => {
    if (foo) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("calling...", posContext); // <-- Now my value is back to it's initial
        }, 3500);
    }
};
```

So, what other options do I have when I want to have access to my values directly from my context?

Comment: why don't you make the `useEffect` async/await? as well as such:
```async seEffect(() => {
   const result = await posContext.activePaymentTabId)...```

Comment: I don't think that will solve my problem

Comment: A. did you try? B. why don't you make a condition on function B that only runs if you already have the value you want. You can put function B in a watcher to make sure it is fired when your value comes in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since context value change is reflected only on initial render, you could pass a callback function to the setter which returns the updated value and pass the context value to `functionB`.

```
const makeCardPayment = () => {
    posContext.handleSetActivePaymentTabId(async function(updatedContext) {
       try {
        const res = await functionA();

        return functionB(res.foo, posContext);

       } catch (error) {

       }
    });
};
```

---

```
const functionB = (foo, posContext) => {
    if (foo) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("calling...", posContext); // <-- Now my value is back to it's initial
        }, 3500);
    }
};
```

Comment: I see. How will my promises be in `makeCardPayment `now when you've added another function?

Comment: @MartinNordström, It will work if you make the callback function async. Although your app will wait until context value is updated

Comment: Seems like `functionA` is not being called at all

Comment: As I said, you need to implement `handleSetActivePaymentTabId` method such that it accepts a callback and passes the updated value to it

Comment: Oh yes, sorry Shubham. I made it so it accepted a callback, but the value is still its initial one.

Comment: Thanks. Because of your answer, I was able to solve it. You pointed me in the right direction.